# Javascript: Saltar entre los distintos inputs y selects pulsando enter

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo dos div, en uno tengo unos inputs y select y en el otro tengo otros. La idea es que se pueda saltar al siguiente input con solo pulsar enter, pero que solo se pueda hacer en el div2 e independientemente de si son input o select. Esto debo hacerlo usando Javascript o Jquery o ambos.

```css
#div1,
#div2 {
  float: left;
  width: 280px;
  height: 280px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="div1">
    <input type=text value="Input de div1">
    <select value="Hey">
      <option>opcion 1 de div 1</option>
      <option>opcion 2 de div 1</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div id="div2">
    <input type=text value="Input de div1">
    <select value="Hey">
      <option>seleccionar opcion</option>
      <option>opcion 1 de div 2</option>
      <option>opcion 2 de div 2</option>
    </select>
    <input type=text value="Otro input para div2">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: el problema ahi es que con teclado el enter en un select se abren las opciones y luego otro enter selecciona la opcion, el value del select tambien cambia si usas las flechas. onda que es un cambio del UX un tanto complicado (TAB cambia entre elementos, enter envia el form)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes asignarle una clase a los elementos y luego seleccionar el siguiente elemento de esa clase.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        #div1,
        #div2 {
            float: left;
            width: 280px;
            height: 280px;
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            overflow: scroll;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="div1">
        <input class="miClase" type=text value="Input de div1">
        <select value="Hey" class="miClase">
            <option>opcion 1 de div 1</option>
            <option>opcion 2 de div 1</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="div2">
        <input type=text value="Input de div1">
        <select value="Hey">
            <option>seleccionar opcion</option>
            <option>opcion 1 de div 2</option>
            <option>opcion 2 de div 2</option>
        </select>
        <input type=text value="Otro input para div2">
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(".miClase").keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                var a = e.target.nextElementSibling;
                a.focus();
                console.log(a.innerHTML);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ¿No hay forma de seleccionarlos sin tener que asignarles clases?

Comment: Otra forma sería hacerlo con el "id"; y la cuestión de hacerlo con clases es porque quieres que en algunos sí funcione y en otros no